# Is it possible to rename interface name programmatically in raspberry

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless, networking

I'm using 2 wifi dongles. First one is used to monitor and second one is used to access internet. Even if I changed /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules as below, at startup wlan0 cannot be assigned. Since wlan1 is used for another device, wlan0 is renamed as rename3. I'm using wlan0 for specific purpose and I'm giving its interface name to a program. How can I set wlan0 permanently?

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="AA-12-00-00-2B-8B", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="e8:4e:06:24:c2:df", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
```

Comment: I've closed this because as per our discussion you'll get better help at U&L.  I would migrate it there directly, but then it will be 4 hours back in the queue; you might as well just cut n' paste it as a new question.   However, U&L doesn't permit cross-posting so this one must be closed first.

Comment: Reposted at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197643/is-it-possible-to-set-interface-name-permanently-in-raspberry

Answer (score 1):

Try using a more unique name that cannot get stomped on, such as `mywifi`.  If that works, then your matching rules are good.  If not, then they aren't.  Right now, it might *appear* as if they do sometimes when the interface ends up with the `wlan` name you wanted -- which it might have even with no rule at all.

Comment: well, I missed to tell something. Actually wlan0 can be assigned but sometimes it fails. When it fails to set wlan0, it tries wlan1 as interface name. If I use symlink, is it certain that the name is not going to change? Maybe "mywifi" cannot be assigned and it will try another name.

Comment: I can't promise you I'm right about the reason, but if you use a symlink with a unique name it will either work or not work, depending on whether your match rules are correct.  I mention that because it's possible that they didn't work at all before, but by coincidence of course the interface will end named wlan0 anyway, making you believe it sometimes worked.  So if this doesn't create the symlink, you need to reconsider the match rules.  If it does, then it always should with that device.

Comment: Do I have to create a folder called dev and a file called mywifi? Should I add this lane SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="...", KERNEL=="wlan*", SYMLINK+="mywifi"
 in "mywifi" ?

Comment: I think I got it. Should I only write SYMLINK+="mywifi"  and thats all?

Comment: Whoops -- sorry!  You can't do this with a network interface because they don't use file nodes in `/dev`!  So **this answer is bunk.**   You should really ask this question on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  You will be waiting forever here otherwise.

Comment: Okay, sorry again about that.  I've edited in what I think the problem is and what you should try, but udev is not an area of expertise for me, so again, you should really ask this where you will get better help.