# How to reserve wlan0 for embeded Wifi on Rasberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3

When I don't have any USB dongles connected to the Raspberry Pi, wlan0 is assigned to the embedded WiFi adapter. 
However, when I have USB WiFi dongle connected, the dongle gets assigned wlan0 and the embedded WiFi addapter gets assigned wlan1.

Is there way to reserve wlan0 for the embedded WiFi adapter?

```
RASPBIAN OS: Linux raspberry3 4.4.11-v7+ #888 SMP Mon May 23 20:10:33 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: *"Is there way to reserve wlan0 for embedded wifi-adapter?"* -> Yep, look into `udev`.

Comment: @goldilocks could you provide more detailed explanation?

Comment: No, but I am sure if you search around online you will find one.  Just leave "raspberry pi" out of your search terms as it is part of GNU/Linux which has been around for more than a decade.  Try "linux udev network interface".  There are probably hundreds or thousands of explanations and examples about it [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=udev+wlan0), on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/udev), and online generally. It may take some time and experimentation for you to work out, but like I said, yes it is possible.

Comment: This crumb trail may provide a short cut through the woods: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29819/is-it-possible-to-rename-interface-name-programmatically-in-raspberry (note link to the re-post in the final comment).  It doesn't exactly explain, but you may want to tuck it away in your mind while you are trying to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to set wlan{number} for wireless card by MAC address.
It needs to add rule to /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules file.
For example:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="b8:27:eb:53:4d:fd", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

MAC address can be reached by ifconfig command.