# 2 wireless dongles in an access point issues

Tags: networking

I have setup an access point and all works fine when I have just the one wifi dongle connected.

However, if I have 2 wifi dongles connected when the system boots up the system connects to the internet (via wlan1) but it does not start up the access point (wlan0 does not register as being associated with the access point).

However, if I boot it with just the one wifi dongle it associates with the access point and I can connect as expected. Then if i plug the second wifi dongle in it connects to the internet and the access point still works and internet forwarding works.

is there some sort of priority issue here with how they are booting? or is it something else im missing?

Cheers
Mark

Comment: Does one of the answers had helped you or do you solved the problem? I so please accept the answer or make your own answer. So that will close your question and it will not pop up again year after year.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=459824) thread which discusses the same/or similar problem you are facing. I didnt read through the entire thread but one person seems to have had success by suppressing the loading of modules by blacklisting them and loading them in a specific order

> by basicbold » Tue Nov 26, 2013 4:06 pm
>
> I also ran into this issue while trying to get two wlan sticks to work simultaneously.
> One was powered by the 8192cu module, the other one was a r8712u. Each of them worked fine as long as you connected them separately. At the moment you tried to run the two of them together, the wlan1 device would not register, even though the modules seemed to load fine.
> For me the solution was to first suppress the loading of the modules by blacklisting and load them in a specific order later on:

One more thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59977/129968) which pretty much comes to the same conclusion.

(Un)fortunately I haven't had the personal experience (pain ?) to have to configure such a setup.

HTH

Comment: It's strange I would have thought it would not matter which one of the 2 was seen as wlan0 or wlan1. As in the config it just specifies the interface and not the hardware name of what to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this with `udev` rules. These can be complex, but basically assigns identifiers based on MAC or some other unique ID. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54113/8697 may help.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53277/8697 for more background on "predictable network interface names". This is already in Ubuntu and is probably coming to Raspbian soon.